# mobile changes when using twitter bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, viewport

i have this example layout using twitter bootstrap:

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="span8">
           <h1> Hello MOBLE WORLD</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

they all look the same in all device.

when i put the meta viewport on the  section

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

on the iphone it looks well different almost as if its cut in half(horrible), i want to know why that happens and what changes and does margins or padding have to do anything with it. thanks

Comment: I've created jsfiddle with your code, and I don't get it where problem is? http://jsfiddle.net/8EAK9/

Comment: And maybe you can try with <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;">

Comment: I'm having the same exact problem.. when I take the maximum-scale and initial-scale out, it looks right, but I don't want people to scale it as the site starts to look terrible. Did you ever find a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is use the fluid grid which basically means using a class of row-fluid instead of row on the wrapper.

Comment: this is no-longer correct for people coming to look at this thread. This is a BS 2 fix, not compatible with 3.